# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>')

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the JSON response from the server and output in my ListView

Code Which Is Giving Me The Error Is:

```
Future<List> getCurrencies() async {
  String cryptoUrl =
      "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=my-key";

  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(cryptoUrl));
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

What should I return in order to solve this error ??

My JSON is of this type :

```
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Bitcoin",
"symbol": "BTC",
"slug": "bitcoin",
"num_market_pairs": 8933,
"date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
"tags": [
"mineable",
"pow",
"sha-256",
"store-of-value",
"state-channels",
"coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
"three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
"polychain-capital-portfolio",
"binance-labs-portfolio",
"arrington-xrp-capital",
"blockchain-capital-portfolio",
"boostvc-portfolio",
"cms-holdings-portfolio",
"dcg-portfolio",
"dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
"electric-capital-portfolio",
"fabric-ventures-portfolio",
"framework-ventures",
"galaxy-digital-portfolio",
"huobi-capital",
"alameda-research-portfolio",
"a16z-portfolio",
"1confirmation-portfolio",
"winklevoss-capital",
"usv-portfolio",
"placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
"pantera-capital-portfolio",
"multicoin-capital-portfolio",
"paradigm-xzy-screener"
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwMR.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function prototype of `jsonDecode` *(it is shorthand for `json.decode`)*

```
// dart:convert 

dynamic jsonDecode(String source, {Object? Function(Object?, Object?)? reviver})  

Type: dynamic Function(String, {Object? Function(Object?, Object?)? reviver})
```

It returns `dynamic`. So appropriate return type of `getCurrencies` will be

```
Future<dynamic> getCurrencies()
```

or simply

```
Future getCurrencies()
```

[jsonDecode Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html)

---

To process the json:

```dart
void processJson(dynamic json) {
  var x = json as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(x['data'][0]['name']); // prints 'Bitcoin'
}
```